# Dynamic PIVOT with all data on single row for each id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have been testing with pivot, which seems to do what i want in the first place. Make the foto meta data name (longname) for example Model, ExiffVersion and many more as the column name and the value (metadata) as row value together with the fotoId. There are over 3000 rows. The Pivot gives the same amount with this query, with 1 property result for each row.

table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FotoMetaData](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [validFrom] [date] NULL,
    [validUntil] [date] NULL,
    [alteredOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [isDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [fotoId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [longname] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [metadata] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FotoMetaData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

EXAMPLE DATA (extract for 1 foto with limited properties due the long list):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (233, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'ImageDescription', N'                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (234, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Make', N'NIKON')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (235, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Model', N'COOLPIX S9700  ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (236, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Orientation', N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (237, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'XResolution', N'300')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (238, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'YResolution', N'300')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (239, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'ResolutionUnit', N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (240, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Software', N'COOLPIX S9700V1.0              ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (241, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'DateTime', N'2014:09:21 13:44:31')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (242, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'YCbCrPositioning', N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (243, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'ExposureTime', N'0,0008')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (244, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'FNumber', N'3,7')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (245, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'ExposureProgram', N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (246, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'ISOSpeedRatings', N'125')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (247, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Unknown', N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (248, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'ImageDescription', N'                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (249, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Make', N'NIKON')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (250, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Model', N'COOLPIX S9700  ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (251, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Orientation', N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (252, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'XResolution', N'300')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (253, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'YResolution', N'300')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (254, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'ResolutionUnit', N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] ([id], [validFrom], [validUntil], [alteredOn], [isDeleted], [fotoId], [longname], [metadata]) VALUES (255, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, N'Software', N'COOLPIX S9700V1.0              ')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[FotoMetaData] OFF
GO
```

PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(longname)FROM (SELECT DISTINCT longname FROM FotoMetaData) AS fotoMetaData 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery =   N'SELECT fotoId, ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM FotoMetaData    PIVOT(MAX(metadata) FOR longname IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

I want that for each foto (fotoId) that all properties are filled in on the same row. There are 11 foto's so i want 11 rows. I know i have to do some group by on the fotoId but i have no idea since i don't know the PIVOT statement well. I have adapted an example i found elsewhere for the dynamic pivot.

Comment: Add some Sample data and expected Output.

Comment: add the table structure and sample data format!!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i was a long weekend away. the structure and example data is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @MaxColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(longname)FROM (SELECT DISTINCT longname FROM FotoMetaData) AS fotoMetaData 

SELECT @MaxColumn= ISNULL(@MaxColumn + ',Max(','')
+ QUOTENAME(longname) +') AS '+ QUOTENAME(longname) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT longname FROM FotoMetaData) AS fotoMetaData 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery =   N'SELECT fotoId,MAX(' + @MaxColumn + ' FROM(SELECT  fotoId,' + @ColumnName + '
FROM FotoMetaData   
 PIVOT(MAX(metadata) FOR longname IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable)a GROUP BY fotoId '
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

This will give you the result but i don't know is there any easy way...